# Calling a function with a parameter inside foreach/map in scala for operating over spark rdd

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase, rdd

I have defined a function which takes two input parameters, one from a spark rdd and an another. Now, I have to call this function on every element of an spark rdd for which I have used map or foreach function but how do I pass the other parameter. Here's explanation:

```
val convert: (String,Int) => Tuple2[ImmutableBytesWritable,Put] = (a,s) => {
                        val p = new Put(a.toString.getBytes())
                        p.add(Bytes.toBytes("mahipal"),Bytes.toBytes("col_2"), s.toString.getBytes())//a.toString.getBytes())
                        println("the value of a is: " + a)
                       new Tuple2[ImmutableBytesWritable,Put](new ImmutableBytesWritable(Bytes.toBytes(a)), p);
                    }
```

To call this function on every element of an spark rdd I would do something like this:  `(newarray1.map(convert))` but how do I pass the other parameter?

Comment: Why don't you define your functions line normal functions with `def`?

Comment: it was throwing not serialisable error. Defining it like this worked.

Comment: Alright, well, you can define a closure within `newarray1.map(` like `newarray1.map(row => convert(row(0), row(1))`

Comment: `(newarray1.map(x=> convert(x, i))` ?

Comment: thanks, this worked.